# Swift Eureka ActionSheetRow options based on the value of another row

Tags: swift, xcode, eureka-forms

I am attempting to have an ActionSheetRow, but I would like the options of this row to be based on the value selected on a different ActionSheetRow. I attempted on placing and if statement before the dependent ActionSheetRow but this did not work. I also attempted to add an if statement before setting the options and this also did not work. Is this something that is possible and if so how would I go about doing this?

Thank you all feed back welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup closure of the `ActionSheetRow` you get the row you want to switch on, see:

```
let row: RowOf<String>! = form.rowBy(tag: "Request")
let value = row.value ?? ""

if value == "1" {
  $0.options = ["A", "B"]
} else {
  $0.options = ["C", "D"]
}
```

That should work.